# Safe break on 404/401 server status response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-promise

I wanna show a message when the server returns 404, or 401.

**This is my structure:**

ultimasOperacionesController -> ultimasOperacionesService -> remoteDataService

**ultimasOperacionesController**: call the service.

**ultimasOperacionesService**: call remoteDataService.

**remoteDataService**: call to the server (the server response with 404).

So this is my part of code to make to request:

**Controller**

```
function cargarUltimasOperacionesComplejo() {

       ultimasOperacionesService.obtenerUltimasOperacionesComplejo()
            .then(function(ultimasOperaciones) {
                vm.ultimasOperaciones = ultimasOperaciones;
            })
            .catch(mostrarError);
    }


    function mostrarError(e) {
        //HERE I WANT TO MAKE SOMETHING TO SHOW A IMAGE TELLING TO THE USER THAT WAS NOT POSSIBLE CONNECT TO THE SERVER.
    }
```

**Service**

```
//funcion para obtener las últimas operaciones
    function obtenerUltimasOperacionesComplejo() {
        remoteDataService.obtenerUltimasOperacionesComplejo()
         .then(function(ultimasOperaciones) {
                return ultimasOperaciones;
            })
            .catch(mostrarError);

    }

    function mostrarError() {
        debugger;
         return $q.reject('Ups! Hubo un problema al conectarse al servidor. Intente nuevamente');
    }
```

**RemoteDataService**

```
function obtenerUltimasOperacionesComplejo() { 
        debugger;
        return $http
            .get(ultimasOperacionesUrl,
                 {params: {idComplejo: 1}})
            .then(function(response) {
            debugger;
                var datos = response.data;
                var status = response.status;

                if(status == 200){   
                    var exito = datos.success;

                    if(exito == 0){
                        return $q.reject(datos);
                    }
                    else if(exito == 1){
                        ultimasOperaciones = datos.ultimasOperaciones;
                        return ultimasOperaciones;
                    }
                }    
            })
            .catch(generarError);
    }

    function generarError(e){
        debugger;
        if (e.message) {
            return $q.reject(e.message);
        }
        return $q.reject('Ups! Hubo un problema al conectarse al servidor. Intente nuevamente');
    }
```

When I debugged it, The service response with 404, then the start the function "generarError" into remoteDataService.

Finally, start the function "generarError" into UltimasOperacionesService and after that: nothing happens: **the function "mostrarError" in the controller never called.**

Also I have the following error in the console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>       at cargarUltimasOperacionesComplejo (ultimasoperaciones.controller.js:25)

In another post someone told me that is because in some function I'm returning nothing.

**How can I make that the error can arrive to the controller and after that I can make something in the HTML?**
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at
>   cargarUltimasOperacionesComplejo (ultimasoperaciones.controller.js:25)

Because ultimasOperacionesService returns $q.reject() or data **ONLY WHEN remoteDataService promise is resolved** (It is not a synchronous operation) and before its value remains undefined,so ultimasOperacionesService.obtenerUltimasOperacionesComplejo() is not a promise that you can handle by .then() or catch().

if you need to handle promise in your controller then you have to return promise from ultimasOperacionesService.

like this :

```
//funcion para obtener las últimas operaciones
    function obtenerUltimasOperacionesComplejo() {
        return remoteDataService.obtenerUltimasOperacionesComplejo();

    }
```